# Centralizar texto em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, reportlab

Boa tarde, estou criando um programa para gerar certificados, porém estou com problema para centralizar os nomes, como eu poderia fazer isso? Pois cada nome é de um tamanho.

Já tentei o center(), mas não deu certo. Segue o código:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.utils import ImageReader
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, landscape, A4
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch

# Caminho para a imagem de fundo
logo = ImageReader('Certificado.png')

# Tamanho da página
size_page = (1235*mm, 873*mm)

# Tamanho Fonte Nome
size_name = 140

# Nome local
name_x = 0
name_y = 1380

# Fonte
font = "Helvetica-Bold"

def GeneratePDF(lista):
    try:
        for indice, nome in enumerate(lista):
            # Gerar certificado
            pdf = canvas.Canvas('{}.pdf'.format(nome))
            # Tamanho da página do certificado
            pdf.setPageSize(size_page)
            # Imagem de fundo
            pdf.drawImage(logo, 0, 0)
            pdf.setFont(font, size_name)
            pdf.drawString(name_x, name_y, '{}'.format(nome))
            pdf.save()
            print('{}.pdf criado com sucesso!'.format(nome))
    except:
        print('Erro ao gerar pdf')

lista = ["Gabriel Nunes Delfino", "Teste"]

GeneratePDF(lista)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Centralizar texto exige que a api de desenho saiba *onde* centralizar seu texto - e é você que tem que fazer essa conta.

Muitas APIs não tem nenhuma função de centralizar automaticamente o texto - nesses casos, você tem que fazer a conta de "onde o canto esquerdo do texto tem que ficar para o texto estar centralizado" - (não é uma conta difícil - é basicamente `x = largura_da_linha / 2 - largura_do_texto / 2` ) .

Se você estivesse trabalhando com `print` no terminal, e não com pdf, o método `.format` e as f-strings podem centralizar um parâmetro num espaço dado - basta colocar dentro das chaves a sequência `:^` seguida do tamanho do espaço em branco. Por exemplo: `"*{:^40}*".format("Stackoverflow")` vai deixar 40 caracteres entre os dois asteriscos e criar uma string com "stackoverflow" centralizado nesse espaço:

```
'*             Stackoverflow              *'
```

No caso do **reportlab**, o [canvas tem o método `drawCentredString`](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) (em vez do `drawString` )  que faz o alinhamento central pra você - mas você tem que passar pra ele o "ponto base" - isso é, em que coordenada "x" você quer que esteja o centro do texto - (a diferença para o método acima é que aqui você passa o centro direto - não precisa calcular a coordenada x do canto esquerdo do texto)

Para calcular o x do "centro" é só pegar a largura da página e dividir por dois. COmo você já tem o page_size, isso fica trivial - basta trocar a linha
`pdf.drawString(name_x, name_y, '{}'.format(nome))` por

```
pdf.drawCentredString(size_page[1] / 2, name_y, nome)
```

(Note que `"{}".format(nome)` não faz nada - format simplesmente devolve uma nova string, substituindo as ocorrências de `{}` pelos parâmetros que você coloca como não tem nada além do `{}` é a mesma coisa que usar o nome direto.)

Uma outra coisa que chama a atenção aí é que você está gerando um PDF com um tamanho fora do convencional - os valores que você usa em `size_page` são em milímetros - podem estar certos se for um banner por que você está pondo 1.2 metros x 80cm, mas se for um certificado, vai querer usar o tamanho A4 que é 297 x 210mm.

Como é um formato vetorial, a qualidade vai ser sempre a mesma - mas se gerar com o "tamanho gigante", se não prestar atenção para redimensionar na hora de imprimir, pode dar errado.

Comment: Meu último voto do dia.

Comment: nossa.  estou há uns 8 anos no s.o. e acho que nunca usei todos os votos. :-) . Ganha qual medalha?

Comment: Ganha essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage

Comment: Não tenho preguiça em votar em conteúdo bom, eu voto mesmo.

Comment: a turma precisava votar mais - - tá cheio de respostas boas por aí com "8 mil visualizações" e dois votos.

Comment: Se eu coloco 297 x 210mm o meu plano de fundo fica muito fora, não consegui outra forma a não ser assim. Tentei o que você passou, não deu certo.

https://github.com/nunesdelfino/Certificado

Comment: Tem uma forma melhor para fazer isso que desejo? Recomandaria algo?

Comment: tem que redimensionar a imagem antes de adicionar ela ao canvas com o `.drawImage` -a documentaçao não é muito boa, e você vai precisar experimentar-  tente passar os parâmetros `width` e `height` quando chamar o drawImage e veja se ele redimensiona a imagem.